# scaml interpolation in html attributes

Tags: dojo, scalate

I have something like this:

```
-@ var id:String

%div{:dojoType => 'dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore', :jsType => 'store', :url => "/path/to/resource?id=#{id}"}
```

I was hoping variable interpolation would work here, but it just puts `#{id}` into the html. I also tried:

```
%div{:url => 'path/to/resource?id='+id}
```

And that doesn't even compile. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
%div{:url => {"/path/to/resource?id="+id}}
```